# Error Sort alphabet list in java

Tags: java, list, sorting

I have to sort a list in alphabetical order.
I tried doing this:

```
        java.util.Collections.sort(Schedario.returnNewListCode());
```

but I get the following error:

```
Bound mismatch: The generic method sort(List<T>) of type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (List<CodeRegistry>). The inferred type CodeRegistry is not a valid substitute for 
 the bounded parameter <T extends Comparable<? super T>
```

any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: Things in the list need to implement `Comparable` interface... that is what the error message is saying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The items in your List need to implement Comparable, not the list itself as the other answer states. You can see this from the somewhat complicated signature of Collections.sort(), this is Java generics gobbledegook for "a list of X where X implements Comparable"

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list) {
```

The following works because String implements java.lang.Comparable

```
Collections.sort(new ArrayList<String>())
```

Following gives same error as you describe as Horse is not Comparable

```
private class Horse {
    private String name;
}
Collections.sort(new ArrayList<Horse>())
```

Solution 1: implement Comparable

```
private class Horse implements Comparable<Horse> {
    private String name;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Horse o) {
        return o.name.compareTo(name);
    }
}
```

Solution 2: use Collections.sort(list, comparator). Useful if you have multiple sort order requirements or the class is not under your control,

```
Collections.sort(new ArrayList<Horse>(), new Comparator<Horse>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Horse o1, Horse o2) {
        return o1.name.compareTo(o2.name);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The items in your list needs to implement Comparable. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html

So that is knows HOW to sort. Otherwise it can't.

Comment: I guess you need to change your wording. `List` interface doesn't implement `Comparable<List>`.

Comment: Yes. Sorry. I'll change it.